# Java - How to Avoid Creating List and Then Copying Into it

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I have this general function to populate an ArrayList of objects from a database.  The problem is that I'm getting a general ArrayList class back from the DB, and then creating the specific subclass of the ArrayList I need to create, and then copying from the generic ArrayList to my subclass.  I want to eliminate that unnecessary step of copying from one array to the other, since the performance won't be great with hundreds of rows.  How can I eliminate that step using generics?

So, to use a more specific example, I have a data class like

```
public class UserData {}
```

and then a class like

```
public class UserSet extends ArrayList<UserData>
```

and I would populate the UserSet object by using a function call like

```
UserSet s = selectAll("SELECT * FROM users", UserSet.class);
```

and my general function to query the DB and return a UserSet instance is like this.

```
public static <T, S extends List<T>> S selectAll(String sql, Class<S> listType, Object...args) throws Exception
{
    // t = UserData.class in my example
    Class<T> t = (Class<T>)((ParameterizedType)listType.getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];

    // From Apache's DBUtils project
    QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
    // AnnotatedDataRowProcessor is my class that just converts a DB row into a data object
    ResultSetHandler<List<T>> h = new BeanListHandler<T>(t, new AnnotatedDataRowProcessor());

    Connection conn = DB.getConnection();
    try
    {
        // creates the new instance of my specific subclass of ArrayList
        S result = listType.newInstance();
        // returns the ArrayList which I then copy into result
        result.addAll(run.query(conn, sql, h, args));
        return result;
    } 
    finally 
    {
        DbUtils.close(conn);  
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, you should not _extend_ `ArrayList`. Remember [_Effective Java,_ Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance.](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/classes-and-interfaces/ch04lev1sec4)

Comment: If you're getting back a list containing elements of the right type, but the API doesn't support a typed return value, you can just cast it.

Comment: Yes, good call on casting.  Not sure why I didn't think of the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your `BeanListHandler`, something like this:

```
ResultSetHandler<List<T>> h = new BeanListHandler<T>(t, new AnnotatedDataRowProcessor()) {
    @Override
    public List<T> handle(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
        List<T> rows = listType.newInstance();
        while (rs.next()) {
            rows.add(this.handleRow(rs));
        }
        return rows;
    }
};
```

You will probably need some casts to make this compile, but this is the general idea.

Then calling `run.query(conn, sql, h, args)` will directly create the type you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to pass in the Class type into the constructor of AnnotatedDataRowProcessor so I wouldn't break the interface methods in this BeanListHandler.

```
private Class<?> type;

public <T> AnnotatedDataRowProcessor(Class<T> type)
{
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
public <T> List<T> toBeanList(ResultSet rs, Class<T> type) throws SQLException
{
    try
    {
        List<T> list = (List<T>)this.type.newInstance();

        while (rs.next())
        {
            list.add(toBean(rs,type));
        }

        return list;
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException ex)
    {
        throw new SQLException(ex.getMessage());
    }
    catch (InstantiationException ex)
    {
        throw new SQLException(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```